# How do I iterate through each JSON's object property in LotusScript

Tags: json, lotus-notes, lotusscript

Consider I have a JSON object like this

```
{
 "someObject": 
  {
   "Object_Name": "objName",
   "Alternative_Name" : "altName",
   "Alias_Name" : "alias"
  }
}
```

How do I iterate through each property of someObject and get key and value accordingly using LotusScript? I've tried this so far

```
Dim vResults As Variant
Dim vResultData As Variant
Dim jsonReader As New JSONReader

Set vResults = jsonReader.Parse(someObjectJSON.ToJSON())

Set vResultData = vResults.GetItemValue("someObject")

ForAll vResult In vResultData.Items
    ForAll tmp In vResult.Items         
           Print "Key: " +  ListTag(tmp) + " Value: " + tmp    
     End ForAll
End ForAll
```

But unfortunately it doesn't work and gives me `ObjectVariable not set` error in forAll loop. What's the problem? Is there any way to solve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works:

```
ForAll item In vResultData.Items
       Print "Key: " +  ListTag(item) + " Value: " + item
End ForAll
```

Here is the complete example:

```
Option Declare
Use "ls.snapps.JSONReader"

Sub Initialize
    Dim sJSON As String
    Dim jsonReader As JSONReader
    Dim vResults As Variant
    Dim vResultData As Variant
    Set jsonReader = New JSONReader
    sJSON = |{
        "someObject": {
            "Object_Name": "objName",
            "Alternative_Name": "altName",
            "Alias_Name": "alias"
        }
    }|
    Set vResults = jsonReader.Parse(sJSON)
    Set vResultData = vResults.GetItemValue("someObject")
    ForAll item In vResultData.Items
        Print "Key: " +  ListTag(item) + " - Value: " + item
    End ForAll
End Sub
```

and the resulting output:

[image]

Comment: List item doesn't exist :(

Comment: Are you sure you test with the example in your question?

Comment: Hmm, now it works... Interesting, must have missed something... Thank you a lot! :)